# Multiple occurrences of variable in yasnippet snippet

Tags: yasnippet

I would like to do create a snippet in which the `${1:}` command is present in multiple locations, allowing me to editing in multiple locations at once.

In particular I would like this snippet to work as "expected".

`cout << "${1:} = " << ${1:} << "\n";`

usage:

1) type cout

2) expand the snippet

3) type the name of the variable you want to print

Comment: In what way does this snippet not work as expected?

Comment: It works like if the first ${1:} were a ${2:}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: cout variable
# key: cvar
# --
cout << "${1:var} = " << $1 << endl;$0
```

I believe the main problem is that `yasnippet` doesn't recognize the second
`${1:}` as a *mirroring* placeholder, and instead attempts to *fix* the snippet
by changing `${1:}` to `${2:}`.

It may be an idea to open an issue on
[Github](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet) to at least issue an warning
during snippet expansion for these kinds of errors, possibly when
`yas-verbosity` is set to a sufficiently high value.